# wrong Total using case-when in MDX

Tags: mdx

If I use the following Negative total instead of previous one i am getting the same output but still not my expected output. Is there anyone to help me out?

```
MEMBER [Measures].[Negative Total] AS
CASE
    WHEN ([Measures].[Total],[Dim Account].[Account Marketing].&[Income]&[Marketing]) < 0
    THEN [Measures].[Total]*-1
    WHEN ([Measures].[Total],[Dim Account].[Account Marketing].&[Income]&[Marketing]) > 0
    THEN 0
END
```

Let me explain what I am trying to achieve. I have a Dimension of [Dim Account] which has the attributes like [Account Type],[Account Activity], [Account Marketing] etc. [Account Type] is income, expense,.. [Account Activity] is like Advertising,Discounts, Sale of sponsorship,etc [Account Marketing] is the combination of those things I mean advertising is the expense whereas discounts is stored as the negative income, so ultimately discounts will be treated as marketing expense That's why my member [Negative Total] is converting the income multiplied by -1 and i want to exclude those income are positive as they are income. I want to display only those converted income and finally add up them. In my MDX, the data are displayed perfectly but added up the original value -43380.4 +18 - 9181.32= -52542.81 that was supposed to be 43380.4 +0 +9181.32= 52561.72. For comparing the original total with expected total I displayed [Measure].[Total] and [Measure].[Negative Total] concurrently. Help me please if you know the trick[image]

```
WITH
MEMBER [Measures].[Negative Total] AS
CASE
    WHEN
        [Dim Account].[Account Marketing].CurrentMember.MEMBER_CAPTION="Marketing" AND
        [Dim Account].[Account Marketing].Properties("Account Type") ="Income" AND
        [Measures].[Total]<1
    THEN [Measures].[Total]*-1

    WHEN 
        [Dim Account].[Account Marketing].CurrentMember.MEMBER_CAPTION="Marketing" AND
        [Dim Account].[Account Marketing].Properties("Account Type") ="Income" AND
        [Measures].[Total]>1 
    THEN 0
END

SELECT
 {
 [Measures].[Total],[Measures].[Negative Total]} on COLUMNS
 , 
NON EMPTY 
 (
    {
        (
        [Dim Account].[HierarchyMarketing].[Account Marketing].&[Income]&[Marketing] 
        *
        {
        [Dim Account].[Account Activity].[Account Activity].MEMBERS,
        VISUALTOTALS([Dim Account].[Account Activity].[All])
        }
        )
     }
    ,
    [Dim Branch].[Trading As].&[BAR]&[Barlens Event Hire] ,
    [Dim Scenario].[Scenario Name].&[Actual]  ,
    [Dim Fiscal Year].[HierarchyFiscal].[E Month].&[2016]&[December]
 )
 on ROWS
FROM [CubeProfitLoss]
```

Comment: I think this is a tricky problem, what i am trying to sort out for a month. please fix it for me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is working as expected since `[All]` too is a member.

To achieve what you want, add a base measure that gets the negative total and then use it in the final calculation.

```
MEMBER [Measures].[Negative Total Test] AS
CASE
    WHEN ([Measures].[Total],[Dim Account].[Account Marketing].&[Income]&[Marketing]) < 0
    THEN [Measures].[Total]*-1
    WHEN ([Measures].[Total],[Dim Account].[Account Marketing].&[Income]&[Marketing]) > 0
    THEN 0
END

MEMBER [Measures].[Negative Total] AS
CASE
    WHEN [Dim Account].[Account Activity].CURRENTMEMBER IS  [Dim Account].[Account Activity].[All]
    SUM(
        [Dim Account].[Account Activity].[Account Activity].MEMBERS,
        [Measures].[Negative Total Test]
       )
   ELSE [Measures].[Negative Total Test]
END
```

Comment: You are the champion!!! You can't realize how happy i am! I was struggling too long time to fix and at last you solved it ! Shabash!!

Comment: (upped) nice answer Sourav

Comment: i have posted my real but very close to this solution under another user @shamim. please have a look

Answer (score 1):

(Just to add to Sourav's nice solution)

`CASE` and `IIF` are both slow - `IIF` can be faster in some circumstances, usually it is faster choice if one of its branches can be `NULL`:

```
MEMBER [Measures].[Negative Total Test] AS
  IIF(
    (
       [Measures].[Total]
      ,[Dim Account].[Account Marketing].&[Income]&[Marketing]
    ) >= 0
      ,NULL
      ,[Measures].[Total] * -1
  )
MEMBER [Measures].[Negative Total] AS
  IIF( 
    [Dim Account].[Account Activity].CURRENTMEMBER 
       IS [Dim Account].[Account Activity].[All]
    ,SUM(
        [Dim Account].[Account Activity].[Account Activity].MEMBERS,
        [Measures].[Negative Total Test]
       )
   ,[Measures].[Negative Total Test]
  )
```

According to the screenshot there is no need to include Marketing in the first calc so a further simplification could be:

```
MEMBER [Measures].[Negative Total Test] AS
  IIF(
    [Measures].[Total] >= 0
   ,NULL
   ,[Measures].[Total] * -1
  )
MEMBER [Measures].[Negative Total] AS
  IIF( 
    [Dim Account].[Account Activity].CURRENTMEMBER 
       IS [Dim Account].[Account Activity].[All]
    ,SUM(
        [Dim Account].[Account Activity].[Account Activity].MEMBERS,
        [Measures].[Negative Total Test]
       )
   ,[Measures].[Negative Total Test]
  )
```

Comment: thanks for your alternative IIF solution instead of Case-When however, this problem was actually a part of my main problem. I have another more condition that needs to be checked using case-when condition. Soon I am going to post my whole problem in another post then you will see and try to solve the whole thing. You guy's are really helpful. I appreciate your concern

Comment: I just checked your solution and worked fine. thanks again

Comment: can you have a look the above answer which is acually a problem please, i am still struggling

Comment: can you have a look the above answer which is acually a problem please, i am still struggling

Comment: I have posted my real but very close to this solution under another user @shamim. please have a look

Answer (score 0):

WOW ! I got my answers, that's the thing I was looking for. It was nothing but only changes is the display of [Negative Total Test]. I again thanks to Saurav because he gave me life of my MDX code.
[image]

```js
WITH
MEMBER [Measures].[Negative Total Test] AS
CASE
    WHEN
        [Dim Account].[Account Marketing].CurrentMember.MEMBER_CAPTION="Marketing" AND
        [Dim Account].[Account Marketing].Properties("Account Type") ="Income" AND
        [Measures].[Total]<1
    THEN [Measures].[Total]*-1

    WHEN 
        [Dim Account].[Account Marketing].CurrentMember.MEMBER_CAPTION="Marketing" AND
        [Dim Account].[Account Marketing].Properties("Account Type") ="Income" AND
        [Measures].[Total]>1 
    THEN NULL
 ELSE 
  [Measures].[Total]
END

MEMBER [Measures].[Negative Total] AS
CASE
 WHEN  [Dim Account].[Account Activity].CURRENTMEMBER IS  [Dim Account].[Account Activity].[All]
 THEN 
 SUM(
        [Dim Account].[Account Activity].[Account Activity].MEMBERS,
        [Measures].[Negative Total Test]
       )
   ELSE [Measures].[Negative Total Test]
END

MEMBER [Dim Account].[HierarchyMarketing].[Income] AS
 ([Dim Account].[HierarchyMarketing].[Account Type].&[Income], [Measures].[Negative Total])

MEMBER [Dim Account].[HierarchyMarketing].[Total Marketing Expense] AS
 AGGREGATE
 (
 {
 [Dim Account].[Account Marketing].&[Income]&[Marketing]
 ,
 [Dim Account].[Account Marketing].&[Expenses]&[Marketing] 
 }
 ,
 [Measures].[Negative Total]
 )

SELECT
 {
 //[Measures].[Total], [Measures].[Negative Total], 
 [Measures].[Negative Total Test]
 } on COLUMNS
 , 
 NON EMPTY 
 (
    {
  (
  [Dim Account].[HierarchyMarketing].[Account Type].&[Income]
  * 
  {
  [Dim Account].[Account Activity].[All]
  } 
  )
  ,
        (
        {
          [Dim Account].[HierarchyMarketing].[Account Marketing].&[Expenses]&[Marketing]
            ,
   [Dim Account].[HierarchyMarketing].[Account Marketing].&[Income]&[Marketing] 
        }
        *
        [Dim Account].[Account Activity].[Account Activity].MEMBERS 
        )
        ,
        (
        [Dim Account].[HierarchyMarketing].[Total Marketing Expense] 
     ,
  [Dim Account].[Account Activity].[All]  
        )
     } 
 ,
// Traders,
 [Dim Branch].[Trading As].&[BAR]&[Barlens Event Hire] ,
 [Dim Scenario].[Scenario Name].&[Actual]  ,
 [Dim Fiscal Year].[HierarchyFiscal].[E Month].&[2016]&[December]
 )
 on ROWS
FROM [CubeProfitLoss]
;
```

[image: If I execute [Measures].[Negative Total Test] commenting MEMBER [Measures].[Negative Total Test] AS -- (1) the output is like this]

[image: If I execute [Measures].[Negative Total Test] commenting MEMBER [Measures].[Negative Total Test] AS -- (2) the output is like this]

I should have asked as an another question however I have reached my question limit, sorry for that.
The above question was the part of my problem. The final output should be like my edited picture. According to Sourav's solution, he checked the condition of [Dim Account].[Account Activity].CURRENTMEMBER IS  [Dim Account].[Account Activity].[All] that worked perfectly that tiny problem but when I wanted to accumulate with original income (650,920.88) then it's coming up with big figure that's not expected. Another solution I need I want to add up marketing expense(24010.44) with negative marketing income which are already converted (43380.4+9181.32) so finally the result should be 76572.16. Please modify my MDX. Thanks a lot

```js
WITH

//MEMBER [Measures].[Negative Total Test] AS -- (1)
//CASE
//    WHEN ([Measures].[Total],[Dim Account].[Account Marketing].&[Income]&[Marketing]) < 0
//    THEN [Measures].[Total]*-1
//    WHEN ([Measures].[Total],[Dim Account].[Account Marketing].&[Income]&[Marketing]) > 0
//    THEN NULL
// ELSE
// [Measures].[Total]
//END

MEMBER [Measures].[Negative Total Test] AS --(2)
CASE
    WHEN
        [Dim Account].[Account Marketing].CurrentMember.MEMBER_CAPTION="Marketing" AND
        [Dim Account].[Account Marketing].Properties("Account Type") ="Income" AND
        [Measures].[Total]<1
    THEN [Measures].[Total]*-1

    WHEN 
        [Dim Account].[Account Marketing].CurrentMember.MEMBER_CAPTION="Marketing" AND
        [Dim Account].[Account Marketing].Properties("Account Type") ="Income" AND
        [Measures].[Total]>1 
    THEN NULL
 ELSE 
  [Measures].[Total]
END

MEMBER [Measures].[Negative Total] AS
CASE
    WHEN [Dim Account].[Account Activity].CURRENTMEMBER IS  [Dim Account].[Account Activity].[All]
    THEN
 SUM(
        [Dim Account].[Account Activity].[Account Activity].MEMBERS,
        [Measures].[Negative Total Test]
       )

   ELSE [Measures].[Negative Total Test]
END
//MEMBER [Dim Account].[Account Activity].[TOTAL] AS
// [Dim Account].[Account Activity].[All]

MEMBER [Dim Account].[HierarchyMarketing].[Total Marketing Expense] AS
 AGGREGATE
 (
 {
 [Dim Account].[Account Marketing].&[Income]&[Marketing]
 ,
 [Dim Account].[Account Marketing].&[Expenses]&[Marketing] 
 }
 ,
 [Measures].[Negative Total Test]
 )


SELECT
 {
 [Measures].[Total], [Measures].[Negative Total]
 } on COLUMNS
 , 
 NON EMPTY 
 (
    {
  (
  [Dim Account].[HierarchyMarketing].[Account Type].&[Income]
  * 
  {
  VisualTotals([Dim Account].[Account Activity].[All])
  } 
  )
  ,

        (
        {
            [Dim Account].[HierarchyMarketing].[Account Marketing].&[Expenses]&[Marketing]
            ,
   [Dim Account].[HierarchyMarketing].[Account Marketing].&[Income]&[Marketing] 
        }
        *
        [Dim Account].[Account Activity].[Account Activity].MEMBERS 
        )
        ,
        (
        [Dim Account].[HierarchyMarketing].[Total Marketing Expense] 
     ,
  VISUALTOTALS([Dim Account].[Account Activity].[All])  
        )
     } 
 ,
 [Dim Branch].[Trading As].&[BAR]&[Barlens Event Hire] ,
 [Dim Scenario].[Scenario Name].&[Actual]  ,
 [Dim Fiscal Year].[HierarchyFiscal].[E Month].&[2016]&[December]
 )
 on ROWS
FROM [CubeProfitLoss]
```

Comment: @SouravA  can you have a look please, i am still struggling

Comment: @SouravA i noticed if I use  WHEN [Dim Account].[Account Activity].CURRENTMEMBER IS  [Dim Account].[Account Activity].[All]
    THEN
 SUM(
        [Dim Account].[Account Activity].[Account Activity].MEMBERS,
        [Measures].[Negative Total Test]
       ) this line along with my total code it is actually summing up twice of  [Dim Account].[Account Activity].[All] that's why the total figure is 1269026 instead of 650920